# Change the center of google maps on browser size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a js noob and I want to put in a line of code that changes the center point of my Google map once my browser is < 675px. I am using v3 of the Google maps API.

I have this code so far which doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(function() {  
  if($('#pgWidth').width() <= 675){
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.50000 , -0.30000));
  } else {
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.50000, -0.30200));
  };
});
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Also your IF-ELSE statements do exactly the same thing

Comment: I changed the code for the post so have now amended the else statement! When changing the browser size the center point isn't changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the resize event, rather than only running the code on document ready:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 675) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.50000 , -0.30000));
  } else {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.50000, -0.30200));
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to be working either, is there any other code I can provide to help? Sorry but I am new to all of this :(

Comment: Instead of checking the width of `#pgWidth` shouldn't you check the width of the window itself?